# Proteus beginner encountering ERC errors

Tags: proteus

```
#I:ISIS Release 8.11.00 (Build 30052) (C) Labcenter Electronics 1990- 2020. #1: Compiling design 'C:\Users\tonyo\OneDrive\Documents\CIRCUITO LUCES SECUENCIALES NE555.pdsprj'. &C=0002, 00000003

ELECTRICAL RULES CHECK

Design:

CIRCUITO LUCES SECUENCIALES NE555.pdsprj

Doc. no.: <NONE>

Revision: <NONE>

Author: <NONE>

Created: 04/07/2022

Modified: 04/07/2022

UNDRIVEN: Ul, GND (Power Pin)

UNDRIVEN: Ul, CV (Input)

UNDRIVEN: U2, E (Input)

UNDRIVEN: U2, MR (Input)

ERROR: GND, <TERM> (Power Rail) connected to U2, CO (Output)

ERROR: VSS, <TERM> (Power Terminal) connected to U2, CO (Output)

Netlist generated OK.

ERC errors found.
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You have the Carry Output connected to Ground.  IC outputs MUST NOT be connected to Ground or Vcc - if not used they should be left unconnected.

All unused INPUTs to CMOS logic ICs must be connected to Vcc or Ground, whichever will allow the IC to work as intended.